# If X is a topological space, U is open in X, A is dense in X, then cl(A∩U)=cl(U)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

One direction is trivial so I just need to show any element in closure of U is in the other set.

If x is in cl(U) then any open neighborhood excluding x intersects U non trivially. Since A is dense the open neighborhood intersects A non trivially. If I can show that x is a limit point of A∩U, I would be done, however how do I show that this open neighborhood intersects U and A at the same points? I can imagine situations where the open neighborhood of x intersect U and A but not the points that U and A share in common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't used that $U$ is open yet...

If $x \in \operatorname{cl}(U)$, let $V$ be *any* open neighbourhood of $x$; we have to show $V$ intersects $A \cap U$.

Firstly, $V$ intersects $U$ as $x \in \operatorname{cl}(U)$, so pick $y \in V \cap U$, and $V \cap U$ is an *open* neighbourhood of $y$ so it must intersect $A$ as $A$ is dense and so $y \in \operatorname{cl}(A)=X$, ergo:

$$\emptyset \neq (U \cap V) \cap A  = V \cap (U \cap A)$$

and so we're done, $x \in \operatorname{cl}(A \cap U)$ as $V$ was arbitrary.

Comment: Note that introducing $y$ is superfluous; it suffices to note that that $U \cap V$ is non-empty and open and so intersects the dense set $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in\overline U$. Then for every open set $V$ such that $x\in V$ we have $V\cap U\ne\varnothing$.

Now, $V\cap U$ is open and nonvoid, so the denseness of $A$ guarantees that $A\cap (U\cap V)\ne\varnothing$. So, given the set $A\cap U$ for every set $V$ with $x\in V$ we have that $(A\cap U)\cap V=A\cap (U\cap V)\ne\varnothing$, wich is the definition of $x\in \overline{A\cap U}$.

Comment: There is *some* open $V$? sure, $V=X$ will do it. But the point is that this holds for **all** open $V$ that contain $x$, and that's what's needed.

Comment: OUCH!!!!! corrected.